# SQL script to show addition to tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a 2 MS SQL 2005 databases,a TEST and DEV database. Now our developer added some extra columns,tables etc in the DEV database.This created differences in the TEST database.is there a script i can write tha can tell me what the changes where in the DEV database between certain dates...i found a couple of tools but they are quite basic and dont really generate change scripts etc. Also tried the change script function in management studio but it seems to be working when the change is first made and not later.
Appreciate your thoughts.

A.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for on the 1st answer.
istnt there a build in SP that can do this?

Comment: No.There is no built-in mechanism in SQL to do a diff on the schema of two databases. You must do it manually or use a third-party tool like SQL Compare.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to manage changes to your database schema and then apply them in a controlled and consistent manner. Moreover, you need a single authoritative source for the database schema.

For all this, check out [Wizardby](https://code.google.com/archive/p/octalforty-wizardby):

[image: Versioning with Wizardby]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://octalforty-wizardby.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/img/database_versioning_with_wizardby.png))</sub>

Comment: OK, ths does a look a cool tool but a bit oo complicated..i am looking for something bit simpler since the changes are not that massive, we are talking bout a column here a column there a new table etc.

Answer (score 0):

[redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlcompare&gclid=CIf7p7H5v6ACFWV75Qodwz2LUw) is a good tool to check for differences between databases and even sync them.

However, if you need to do this for free, try this: within in SQL Server Management Studio do the following:

1) script the entire schema of TEST to a file, [look here if you don't know how](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/)
2) repeat step #1 but for the DEV database
3) diff the files using something like [Beyond Compare, should have a 30 trial](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote dbscript, and one of its features is to [compare two database schemas](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/07/06/synching-sql-server-databases/) and create a migration script.